# Launch Windows 8 Nokia Maps

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, here-api

How to use Nokia Maps in Windows 8 Store application ? I used it before in windows phone 8 but I can't find any sdk for Windows 8

Comment: It's considered polite to mark the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing preventing Nokia from making their Navteq map control similar to their map control in Windows Phone. In the meantime, developers have the Bing map control, which is a Navteq-based map.

If you think about it for a second, Nokia's investment in Phone makes sense that they would spend the time to build a Native Navteq map. In fact their Phone control is shared across apps, literally built into the Phone's core OS. They may not be as motivated to build one for Windows 8. And, and this is serious, their resulting Windows 8 control would NEVER have the same functionality as Phone until it is shipped as a part of the core framework (similar to phone). I hope this makes sense.

Some resources:

> More info on the Bing mapping services
>   http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/06/easily-include-bing-map-data-in-your.html
>
> More info on the Bing mapping control
>   http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/10/announcing-windows-8-bing-maps-sdk-is.html

Best of luck!